# Where can I find Apache Jena versions history?

Tags: java, jena, revision-history

I'm looking for information when Jena 2.0 was released and what was Jena version when Apache had taken it from HP (2009). I was looking for it Jena GitHub, but first commit in this service was already in 2.7 RC version (https://github.com/apache/jena/commits/trunk?page=70). Besides Googling I've checked Jena archives repository (http://archive.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries), but it also dates back only to 2012 when Jena 2.7 was released. Where can I find older releases (not necessarily binaries, I need build info + date) of Jena? I need this for research purpose.

Comment: It's clear that you've done some research on this, and you've explained the issue, so I won't downvote.  However, "**Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow**".  I think you'd be much more likely to get quick and accurate responses from the jena-users mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for understanding, I will take this into account next time.

Comment: The modern Apache change log is in JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/JENA?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin%3Arelease-page&status=released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jena moved from sourceforge to apache during 2.0. You can find pre-apache versions [there](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jena/files/Archive/Jena/).

The answers according to that:

- Jena 2.0 was released 2003-08-28.
- Last sourceforge release was Jena-2.6.4 (2010-12-12).

It isn't obvious from the sourceforge pages, but you can browse jena's history in [cvs](http://jena.cvs.sourceforge.net/) and [svn](http://jena.svn.sourceforge.net/) (which held related components like arq and fuseki).

Comment: Another not-obvious thing is that Apache SVN tree has history from SourceForge SVN.

Comment: Yes, you have to check out the root rather than trunk to see that. Good old svn.